# Add time display bar on Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display the local time which is based on a local timezone of the user visiting my page.
Recently I added this code to my `application_controller.rb` file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :date_loaded
  def date_loaded
    Time.now
  end
end
```

I am very new to Rails and not sure what to do as a next step. Should I add `<%= @date_loader %>` string to my `application.html.erb` and then create a bar in which time will be displayed using my `application.css.scss` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems reasonable. It's not clear why you need a helper method for the current date, though.

Comment: To call it directly from application.html.erb?

Comment: You can simply call `<%= Time.now %>` to get the same result.  Helpers are more useful to DRY up your code where it would otherwise appear in several places...

Comment: Sometimes helpers obscure what you're actually doing. Creating a helper for something that's called once in a template, where the method name is longer than the equivalent call, does not always provide much in the way of benefits.

Comment: As a note, since this is a method, you call it as `<%= date_loaded %>`.

Comment: Thank you! The final question is how should my application.html.erb looks in order to display current time on my main page?

Comment: Well, it should have that `<%= date_loaded %>` part in it somewhere, presumably. If you load any page using that layout you should see it.